# print QrCode with more than 125 characters esc/pos javascrypt

Tags: javascript, string, qr-code, escpos

I'm trying to print a qrCode in esc/pos (page mode) using javascript. The printer is Epson TM-T20X

When I put less than 125 characters in the QrCode it works perfectly but more than that makes the printer stuck and eventually (after trying to print a test  page a few times) it prints a bunch of weird characters.

the test qrCode string is as follows: *aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaa*

code:

````
        var inAux = QRcode.length + 3;
        var pL = inAux%256
        var pH = inAux/256
        var size = 3;

        impressao += Char(29)+Char(40)+Char(107)+Char(4)+Char(0)+Char(49)+Char(65)+Char(49)+Char(0); // Select the model (1)
        impressao += Char(29)+Char(40)+Char(107)+Char(3)+Char(0)+Char(49)+Char(67)+Char(size); // Size Module
        impressao += Char(29)+Char(40)+Char(107)+Char(3)+Char(0)+Char(49)+Char(69)+Char(48); // Correction Level (L)
        impressao += Char(29)+Char(40)+Char(107)+Char(pL)+Char(pH)+Char(49)+Char(80)+Char(48); // Store the data in the symbol storage area
        impressao += QRcode;
        impressao += Char(29) + Char(40) + Char(107) + Char(3) + Char(0) + Char(49) + Char(81) + Char(48); // Print the symbol data in the symbol storage area
        impressao += esc + Char(12); // print page mode (ESC FF)```
````

Comment: Can you give the code showing how do you calculate pL and pH?

Comment: Sure. inAux = QRCode.length + 3; and so pL = inAux%256 and pH = inAux/256

Comment: Well.. I didn't find anything better than this description: https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=144. It says "If there is any error described below in the data of the symbol storage area, it cannot be printed: ... if the data of the symbol storage area is more than the data allowed by specified model and data compaction mode. (This case is an abnormal number of data.)". I didn't find a confirmation but it feels like 125 is a limit of the specific model

Comment: Why not try sending the command with another tool like this and see what happens? [Send Data Tool](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=5027&scat=47&pcat=52)